# How to integrate MoPub inside a shared library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mopub

I need to integrate MoPub inside an android library shared by 3 different games.

I tried to use the fabric plugin with no success... after some attempts I get this error:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.mopub.volley:mopub-volley:1.1.0
```

Then I also tried to follow this guide that you can find here (https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started) but I always get some errors (I can't execute the gradle command via terminal or I get the same error as mentioned above).

Can someone help me?
Thank you,

Mirko

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Edward I was able to import correctly mopub-sdk in my project.

In order to fix the mopub-volley error, first clean the solution, read which files are missing in the console, look at the path, recreate the indicated path and add mopub-volley-1.1.0.jar, mopub-volley-1.1.0.pom in that folder.
Rebuild and you are ready to go!

> In my case, mopub-sdk was looking for the mopub-volley lib inside an
>   inexistent folder in the same path of the android sdk.

If you get another error related to the millenial sdk, add this line in the dependencies section of the build.gradle file inside the mopub-sdk library:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

you should get something like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0'
  compile 'com.mopub.volley:mopub-volley:1.1.0'
}
```

Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go download the MoPub SDK.
2. Unzip and you will get a mopub-sdk folder
3. Navigate to your ‘Project location’, go into your project folder, and drop the unzipped mopub-sdk into the folder.
4. Navigate back to Android Studio and open your project's settings.gradle file and include the MoPub SDK as a module as shown below. You may need to sync Gradle again in Android Studio to have the ‘mopub-sdk’ show up in the left Project window.

   include ':app', ':mopub-sdk'
5. Open your project's build.gradle file and add jcenter as a repository and the MoPub SDK as a dependency:

   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }

   ...

   dependencies {
       compile project(':mopub-sdk')
   ...
   }

Comment: Hi Edward,
Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this error remains:

    Error:Failed to resolve: com.mopub.volley:mopub-volley:1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

For those late to the party:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

just make sure you've added jcenter() in the your repositories. fabric does not do this automatically for some reason

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no mopub-volley lib into mavencentral or jcenter
So tou can try to use

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.mopub.volley:mopub-volley:1.1.0'
```

It helps for me.